# Why does assigning an array to null create an empty array?

Tags: c#, arrays, null, debugging

This is one of those weird ones that feels like I must be seeing things, but here is some code I am debugging:

```
    private byte[] myCode = null;

    ...

    public bool Tampered
    {
        get
        {
            return Bytes == null;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value)
            {
                if (Bytes != null)
                {
                    ProcessBytes();         /* BREAKPOINT HERE */
                    myCode = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I run my code, which executes `someObject.Tampered = true;` and breaks on the breakpoint. At this point, the debugger shows `mycode == bytes[3]`. All is well. I step over ProcessBytes. All is still well.

Then, I step over `myCode = null;` and the debugger shows `myCode == bytes[0]`.

What's going on? Have I just somehow fundamentally broken something? myCode isn't a property, so it shouldn't be doing anything odd. Is there some quirk of arrays in C# that I've somehow previously not known about?

Comment: Oh, never mind. It was all my fault. Stating the problem out loud helped though. Turns out the debugger was calling 'get' which called the Bytes property, which re-created the array.

Comment: You take my time to test your fault.

Answer (score 1):

I think the debugger might be showing you the type of `myCode`, which is in this case an (unassigned) `byte` array with zero length.